# rosrun is unable to find packages

Tags: bash, ros

I am new to ROS, but just can't seem to get past the following error
[rospack] Error: package 'minimal_nodes' not found

I am sourcing the necessary bash scripts in my ~/.bashrc file
source ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

But i always get the error. Could someone help me out ?

Edit 24th August: Here are the contents of package.xml and cmakelists.txt found in minimal_nodes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>minimal_nodes</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The minimal_nodes package</description>

  
  <maintainer email="wyatt@todo.todo">wyatt</maintainer>


  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(minimal_nodes)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependencies might have been
##     pulled in transitively but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES minimal_nodesmal_publish
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a cpp library
# add_library(minimal_nodes
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/minimal_nodes.cpp
# )
## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(minimal_publisher src/minimal_publisher.cpp)
add_executable(sleepy_minimal_publisher src/sleepy_minimal_publisher.cpp)
add_executable(minimal_subscriber src/minimal_subscriber.cpp)
add_executable(minimal_simulator src/minimal_simulator.cpp)
add_executable(minimal_controller src/minimal_controller.cpp)
## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library
## as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes
# add_dependencies(minimal_nodes_node minimal_nodes_generate_messages_cpp)

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
target_link_libraries(minimal_publisher  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(sleepy_minimal_publisher  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(minimal_subscriber  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(minimal_simulator  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(minimal_controller  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS minimal_nodes minimal_nodes_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )
#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_minimal_nodes.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sourcing the environment where `minimal_nodes` should be but the package can't be found, this most likely means the package isn't being built. Making sure `~/ros_ws/src/minimal_nodes/` have `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` that contain the correct package name as well as install the actual executables into `devel`. You should also make sure they are being made with `catkin_make` by just watching the output.

Comment: This is the directory structure of the source files

Comment: This is the directory structure of the source files                                                          ~/ros_ws/src/learning_ros/minimal_nodes$ 
ls reveals the following contents in the folder CMakeLists.txt  launch/  package.xml  README.md  src/ . Build executed succesfully with following output [ 20%] Built target minimal_subscriber
[ 40%] Built target minimal_controller
[ 60%] Built target minimal_simulator
[ 80%] Built target minimal_publisher
rosrun minimal_nodes minimal_publisher
[rospack] Error: package 'minimal_nodes' not found

rosrun executed from ros_ws

Comment: It doesn't look like that package is actually setup to be called `minimal_nodes`. You'll need to edit your post with your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` got us to tell for sure, though.